# Intellij IDEA-Grails GDSL Not Working

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, dsl

I tried to use GDSL Scripts for my grails project in IDEA.

I tried things as shown in the Guide: [GDSL Guide](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/GRVY/Scripting+IDE+for+DSL+awareness). The Steps I followed were:

1. Created a myDef.gdsl file in my project home(i.e. in the folder
   that containg grails-app, web-app etc)
2. In that file i added this code:

   ```
   def ctx2 = context(ctype: "com.myPackage.MyClass")

   contributor(ctx2) {
       method(name: 'withLock', type: 'void', params: [closure: { }])
   }
   ```
3. Clicked on Activate.

But it still does not show any autocomplete or recognise when I do:

```
Myclass m = new MyClass()
m.withLock() //This is not recognised
```

What am I doing wrong??? :(

Details:

- **Idea Series:** Ultimate
- **Idea Version:** 107.535

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The GDSL file should be located under some source root. Grails module content roots aren't source roots. So please consider putting it into src/main/groovy, for example.

Comment: Thanks, I was also wondering about this. Just wanted to add that I was a bit confused about whether it had to be located on the source root or if I could put it in a package; apparently it can be placed in any package.